# What is the fate of a 'lazy Muslim' making shahada before death?

Tags: death, shahada

If there was a Muslim who prays their obligatory prayers rarely (because they are lazy), reads Quran most of the time, gives charity always, loves Allah SO MUCH that their heart hurts in a good way, thanks Allah all the time, fasts in Ramadan (becomes a good Muslim in this month+prays), but at the same time also watches movies/tv, sometimes hears music (but doesn't take it seriously), and go out with people who have a bad influence (but always regrets it).

If one day this person is in their deathbed and they say 'la ilaha illa Allah' and then dies, what is their fate?

I know that none of us can judge or know anyone's fate, but all i'm asking is that is there anything from the Quran or hadith or anything that talks about this kind of people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not trying to hate or anything but I’m struggling to draw connections.

Prayer is something that connects you to Allah. How can you feel strong compassion to Allah when a person doesn’t pray? Surely if they love Allah so so much, being lazy shouldn’t be an obstacle for them to hasten to their Lord.

You’re going to be sinning for missing your prayers and repentance is a key.

Same with Ramadan, how can one forsake prayer after committing to prayer all 30 days?

How can one read Quran all the time but not pray?

Despite the fact they die on their deathbed with the shahada on the tongue, you need to take this into consideration:

- The sins. It’s unlikely for 335 days a year (minus the 30 days in Ramadan) they don’t pray, but listen to music, hang out with bad influences; the chance of them dying with the Shahada on their tongue is very slim—it’s an unrealistic chance. Because while they do read the Quran, their heart fully wouldn’t be connected to Allah because they never prayed and their heart wouldn’t fully be reflecting on the words of their creator if they continue to sin.

So I can’t say what you ask is a possibility because it isn’t. A heart not attached towards Islam isn’t likely to have the honor of saying the Shahada.

For better context, [check out this video.](https://youtu.be/GFLcp9vbt74)

So on their deathbed, the thought of Shahada wouldn’t be on their mind and all the sins they have left not repented would drag them to Jahanam because they were not those who prayed (excluding Ramadan).